# Prove the statement, For all integers $n ≥ 0$, $y_n = 3 * 2^n + 4^n$ where $y_0 = 4, y_1 = 10$ and when $n ≥ 2$, $y_n = 6y_{n-1} – 8y_{n-2} $

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

So approaching this problem

For all integers $n ≥ 0$,  $y_n = 3 * 2^n + 4^n$ where $y_0 = 4, y_1 = 10$ and when $n ≥ 2$, $y_n = 6y_{n-1} – 8y_{n-2} $

I realise that is probobly needs to be proved by induction I have the base cases done for $y_0=4$ and $y_1=10$ but I am having a hard time finding out the inductive step I need to take.

Comment: Just calculate $6y_{n-1}-8y_{n-2}$ from the above formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume this holds for all $y_0, y_1, \ldots y_k$ with $k \ge 1$ and let's prove it for $k \ge 2$. We have
$$
\begin{split}
y_k &= 6y_{k-1} - 8y_{k-2} \\
    &= 6\left(3 \cdot 2^{k-1} + 4^{k-1}\right) - 8\left(3 \cdot 2^{k-2} + 4^{k-2}\right) \\
    &= 9\cdot 2^k + \frac{3}{2} 4^k - 6\cdot 2^k - \frac{1}{2} 4^k \\
    &= 3\cdot 2^k + 4^k,
\end{split}
$$
as desired.

---

For the sake of completeness, this is a recurrence relation with constant coefficients, so you could solve it analytically without having to guess and use induction. So let $y_k - 6y_{k-1} + 8y_{k-2} = 0$ with the initial conditions $y_0=4$ and $y_1=10$.

Assuming $y_k = a^k$ we get the characteristic equation
$$
0 = a^2-6a+8 = (a-2)(a-4)
$$
so the roots are $a=2$ and $a=4$, which implies
$$
y_n = A\cdot 2^n + B \cdot 4^n
$$
and now apply the initial conditions to find a linear system of 2 unknowns and 2 equations for $A$ and $B$:
$$
\begin{split}
 4 &= y_0 &=  A &+ B\\
10 &= y_1 &= 2A &+ 4B
\end{split}
$$
The second equation is equivalent to $A+2B=5$ and subtracting the first one yields $B=1$, plugging back into the the first one yields $A=4-1=3$. Hence,
$$
y_n = 3\cdot 2^n + 4^n
$$